# How do I use Ruby debugger in Emacs?

Tags: ruby, debugging

I am writing Ruby in Emacs, but my Emacs skills are actually pretty low. What I can do, is open the project, TDD using M-x rinari-test, or play inferior Ruby in the second window using M-x run-ruby. Now I woul like to start using debugger from StdLib. I am able to summon it from irb by saying:

```
require 'debug'
```

Upon which I get into a prompt

```
(rdb:1)
```

but there my aptitude ends. I don't even know how to step into a file. Typing 'help' brought a screenful, but it didn't help me to finally start debugging my buggy gem. Online, everybody writes about things such as "rdebug" or "ruby-debug" or whatever which I firstly don't want to use and secondly, being a muggle, I am unable to install on my Debian. Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to try reading the output of `help` in the debugger. It explains the commands nicely.

For instance, for practice, try this at the command-line, not inside an editor/IDE:

```
ruby -rdebug -e 'p 1'
h
```

Ruby's debugger will output the help summary:

```
Debugger help v.-0.002b
Commands
  b[reak] [file:|class:]<line|method>
  b[reak] [class.]<line|method>
                             set breakpoint to some position
  wat[ch] <expression>       set watchpoint to some expression
  cat[ch] (<exception>|off)  set catchpoint to an exception
  b[reak]                    list breakpoints
  cat[ch]                    show catchpoint
  del[ete][ nnn]             delete some or all breakpoints
  disp[lay] <expression>     add expression into display expression list
  undisp[lay][ nnn]          delete one particular or all display expressions
  c[ont]                     run until program ends or hit breakpoint
  s[tep][ nnn]               step (into methods) one line or till line nnn
  n[ext][ nnn]               go over one line or till line nnn
  w[here]                    display frames
  f[rame]                    alias for where
  l[ist][ (-|nn-mm)]         list program, - lists backwards
                             nn-mm lists given lines
  up[ nn]                    move to higher frame
  down[ nn]                  move to lower frame
  fin[ish]                   return to outer frame
  tr[ace] (on|off)           set trace mode of current thread
  tr[ace] (on|off) all       set trace mode of all threads
  q[uit]                     exit from debugger
  v[ar] g[lobal]             show global variables
  v[ar] l[ocal]              show local variables
  v[ar] i[nstance] <object>  show instance variables of object
  v[ar] c[onst] <object>     show constants of object
  m[ethod] i[nstance] <obj>  show methods of object
  m[ethod] <class|module>    show instance methods of class or module
  th[read] l[ist]            list all threads
  th[read] c[ur[rent]]       show current thread
  th[read] [sw[itch]] <nnn>  switch thread context to nnn
  th[read] stop <nnn>        stop thread nnn
  th[read] resume <nnn>      resume thread nnn
  p expression               evaluate expression and print its value
  h[elp]                     print this help
  <everything else>          evaluate
```

The important commands to start with are `s`, `n`, `c` and `b`, and `q`.

- `s` steps into a method.
- `n` steps over a method.
- `c number` runs (continue) until you reach line `number`.
- `b number` sets a breakpoint on line `number`. After setting your breakpoints use `c` to continue running until that line is executed.
- `q` exits the debugger.

Personally, I use the [debugger](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) gem. Others use [PRY](http://pryrepl.org), which is similar to IRB, but with debugger-like extensions.

Knowing how to use a debugger is a good skill. There are problems you can trace down quickly using a debugger, that will take longer trying to use `puts` statements, because you can see what a variable contains interactively, or loop conditionally until a variable contains a certain value.

Comment: Great. I was able to repeat the steps you suggested. Now this is my question: In the same directory, there is file `sy.rb` containing my buggy program. How do I step into its first line?